# Why don't functions marked as "hidden" throw an error when called from external modules in gcc 4?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I'm using gcc. 4.4.7.  If I mark a function as hidden in module A.h:

```
//module A.h
__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden"))) void foo() { ... }
```

I can obviously still call foo from within module A.h. If I have a second module B.h that references A::foo:

```
//module B.h
#include "A.h"
foo();
```

Why isn't an error thrown? If A::foo is technically undefined in module B?

**edit** removed "nothing happens when foo is called in module B". had some code set up wrong

**edit2** I'm looking at [this tutorial](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) for setting up local references in a header file so that they can't be called from other modules. Maybe I'm missing something?

**edit3** I am compling with -fvisibility=hidden

Comment: First of all, please *don't* put actual function definitions in header files! It confuses things immensely.

Comment: Do you mean compilation unit with module?

Comment: Perhaps I have some terminology confused that I didn't know I was confusing.. what's the difference?

Comment: The resource you mention only speaks of *dynamic shared objects* (i.e. `.so` files) which are a far more coarse unit than individual C files.

Comment: ah I see. Then I must be misunderstanding what is happening with the preprocessor. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quote from the GCC Manual:](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)

> ### visibility ("visibility_type")
>
> This attribute affects the linkage of the declaration to which it is attached. There are four supported visibility_type values: default, hidden, protected or internal visibility.
>
> [...]
>
> #### hidden
>
> Hidden visibility indicates that the entity declared has a new form of linkage, which we call “hidden linkage”. Two declarations of an object with hidden linkage refer to the same object if they are in the **same shared object**.

Two compilation units which are linked together are in the **same shared object**.

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling this code with the -fvisibility=hidden flag? If so, then try

```
#pragma GCC visibility push(hidden)
```